# installation failed with message install_failed_uid_changed

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I am running android app from android studio but failed to installed. Although I have uninstalled the app from mobile and have enough memory space in the mobile.
[image] . Please What should I do. I have attached the alert .

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If your device is rooted you can try deleting your application's data from the device. To do so, delete `/data/data/[app package name]` folder or run `adb shell rm /data/data/<app-package-name>`. Then, try to install your app again.

Answer (score 0):

For non-rooted device:

1. Change the ApplicationId of the app. Refer [this](http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/new-build-system/applicationid-vs-packagename) link to change ApplicationId.
2. Build and install the app. The app will install successfully because it is treated as the new app.
3. Now uninstall this app which will clear the data.
4. Now change the ApplicationId to the previous one.
5. Build and install. It will install.

For rooted device:
Just delete

> "/data/data/your.package.name"

on your device